# apple pay token implementation with nodejs and stripe

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, applepay

I want to implement the stripe payment gateway into my project where I will get the Apple Pay token from the client side. but how could I pass it because when I am trying to pass it stripe will through an error StripeInvalidRequestError: Invalid string: eyJkYXRhIj...FfdjEifQ==; must be at most 5000 characters

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount: 1*100,
            currency: 'usd',
            payment_method_types: ['card'],
            payment_method_data: {
                type: 'card',
                card: {
                    token:  req.body.AppleToken // Payment token received from iOS app
                }
            }
        });

        // Process the payment request with Stripe
        const paymentResult = await stripe.paymentIntents.confirm(paymentIntent.id);
        // If payment is successful
        if (paymentResult.status === 'succeeded') {
            res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'Payment successful' });
        } else {
            res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: 'Payment failed' });
        }
```

I am getting error
StripeInvalidRequestError: Invalid string: eyJkYXRhIj...FfdjEifQ==; must be at most 5000 characters
Does anything have any idea about how to pass the apple token into the stripe?

Answer (score 0):

Using raw Apple Pay tokens with Stripe is discouraged. You can use the [Express Checkout Element](https://docs.stripe.com/elements/express-checkout-element), [Payment Element](https://docs.stripe.com/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements), or [Mobile Payment Element](https://docs.stripe.com/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=ios&mobile-ui=payment-element), that all support Apple Pay out-of-the-box.

If you really need to use raw Apple Pay tokens for some reason, you could try talking to [Stripe Support](https://support.stripe.com/?contact=true).